# how to download/fetch file in microsoft sharepoint using sails js

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, automation, sails.js, integration

Assuming that the Sharepoint is already authenticated. Below is my code and I keep on getting an error that the xlsx file is unsupported file.

Currently I am using this library to fetch xlsx file in sharepoint folder.

`const sp = require('@pnp/sp-commonjs').sp; const SPFetchClient = require('@pnp/nodejs-commonjs').SPFetchClient;`

Did I miss something on this code? I don not know if I was able to get the data inside the file, the only way for me to determine if it was a successful fetching is through the file created but it shows that it was a unsupported file.

```
const list = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(process.env.SP_LIST);
const columnsToSelect = ['FileLeafRef', 'Modified'];
const sortDescending = true;

const items = await list.items.select(...columnsToSelect).orderBy('Modified', sortDescending).getAll();
const latestFileUrl = `/sites/sharepointFolder`;
const files = await sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(latestFileUrl).files.orderBy("TimeLastModified", false).top(1).get();

const file = files[0];
const fileUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl;

 sp.web
      .getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl)
      .getBuffer()
      .then((buffer) => {
        // Save the file locally
       // const filePath = path.join(__dirname, fileName);
        fss.writeFileSync(`C:\\folder\\path\\${file.Name}`, buffer);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error fetching file: ${err}`);
      });
```

Comment: You can try to use Graph API to [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get-content?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)/[get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) files in SharePoint site.